# Cannot access backend after upgrading to 3.3

Tags: joomla

I just recently upgraded our test environment Joomla 3.2.x to Joomla 3.3. All requirements were met. I ran the update, and immeditally got the error:

Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.10 or higher to run this version of Joomla!

My current PHP version is 5.3.3.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Neo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version numbers work from left to right. Joomla is saying that it require PHP major version 5, minor version 3 and revision 10. But you currently have PHP major version 5, minor version 3 and revision 3 installed. Revision 3 is less than revision 10, hence it wont work.

I'm guessing you read 5.3.10 as 5.3.1.0 or something like that.

Comment: Thanks Dom. That is the mistake I made...i feel foolish now :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have modified the configuration files for your web server to point to the correct version of php.

Try using `phpinfo()` to see what version you are running with your current settings.

Comment: I did do that. Dom below saw my error. We are looking at updating our machine.